# How is this even possible ? I tried to copy text from PDF it worked

Tags: pdf, image-processing, east-text-detector

**this is a Pdf document**

[image]

**I tried to copy handwritten text from this pdf document and surprisingly it worked. How is this possible.**

Copied Text :

[image]

Comment: It was OCR'd when the PDF files was made. The PDF file contains plain text, with the scanned image overlaid. When you select text, it selects the text that is written behind the image.

Comment: can u please elobarate

Comment: other hand written PDFs are not showing this property